# Unknown Account DApp Tutorial from learnweb3.io

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, ethereumjs

I'm learning the tutorial from https://github.com/LearnWeb3DAO/BasicFrontEndTutorial to create an Ethereum DApp with etherjs. This is my HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

 <title>Ethersjs Demo</title>
 <style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

<script charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/scripts/ethers-v4.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h1>This is my Ethersjs Demo!</h1>
        <p> Here we can set or get the mood: </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col offset-md-4 col-md-4">
                <label for="mood">Input Mood:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mood">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col offset-md-4 col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="getMood()"> get Mood </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-light btn-block" onclick="setMood()"> set Mood</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    window.ethereum.enable()
    var provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider, 'ropsten');

    var MoodContractAddress = "0x7D8CBd7De0b4651432b4367ce2B9E5201bB59c5b";
    let MoodContractABI = [
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [],
            "name": "getMood",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "_mood",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "setMood",
            "outputs": [],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ]

    provider.listAccounts().then(function (accounts) {
        signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
        MoodContract = new ethers.Contract(MoodContractAddress, MoodContractABI, signer);
    })

    async function getMood() {
        getMoodPromise = MoodContract.getMood();
        var Mood = await getMoodPromise;
        alert("The current mood is: " + Mood);
    }

    async function setMood() {
        mood = $("#mood").val()
        if (mood == "") {
            alert("Please input mood");
        } else {
            setMoodPromise = MoodContract.setMood(mood);
            await setMoodPromise;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is the window when I launched the html file
[image]

When I tried to "Set Mood", the error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: contract not deployed (contractAddress="0x7D8CBd7De0b4651432b4367ce2B9E5201bB59c5b", operation="getDeployed", version=4.0.45)

How do I fix this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just as it says, "uncaught promise". Write a catch after your promise statements to receive the MetaMask error, in this case:

```
async function setMood() {
        mood = $("#mood").val()
        if (mood == "") {
            alert("Please input mood");
        } else {
            setMoodPromise = await MoodContract.setMood(mood)
                .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
        }
    }
```